# How can I listen to just part of a single song, or just skip some time?

Tags: itunes, music

Sometimes I just want to listen to part of a song.

In Youtube I can set start/end times for a particular video.  I'm [listening to this song](https://itun.es/us/LvGofb?i=1161430496) and only want to start at 2:50, and end somewhere else.

This example is a 6 minute song... but I'm sure there are other refrains/etc in pop music that could want this.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to a Mac, you can right-click the song, then go into **Get Info** → **Options**, where you can then set both **Start** and **Stop** times.

These preferences will propagate to your iOS devices next time you synchronize them to your iTunes Music Library. If you subscribe to **iTunes in the Cloud** (via iTunes Match or MUSIC), that will be done over the air.

This is a persistent modification that will apply every time you listen to that song (until you reset the **Start** and **Stop** times).